# Servlet requests are executed sequentially for no apparent reason in Glassfish v3

Tags: java, servlets, multithreading, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I'm using Glassfish 3 Web profile and can't get http workers to execute concurrently requests on a servlet.

This is how i observed the problem. I've made a very simple servlet, that writes the current thread name to the standard output and sleep for 10 seconds :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000); // 10 sec
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
```

And when i'm running several simultaneous requests, I clearly see in the logs that the requests are sequentially executed (one trace every 10 seconds).

```
INFO: http-thread-pool-8080-(2)
(10 seconds later...)
INFO: http-thread-pool-8080-(1)
(10 seconds later...)
INFO: http-thread-pool-8080-(2)
```

etc.

All my GF settings are untouched - it's the out-of-the-box config (the default thread pool is 2 threads min, 5 max if I recall properly).

I really don't understand why the sleep() block all the others worker threads. Any insight would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: It would be good to look at the client code calling this in your test.  Your code looks fine here. Perhaps it is the test client that is wrong and not your server code.

Comment: It's definitely the client, and it's absolutely normal: Once it reaches its maximum number of connections, your logs will look as if it runs sequentially. BTW, I'm not guessing here, I had the exact same setup: GFv3, default settings, even the same servlet (sleeping 5 seconds instead of 10 in my case).

Comment: Yes it was the client; I was (stupidely) sending manual requests using a browser. Poor test practice. Thanks :)

Comment: I suggest using [Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for more professional webapp performance testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris nailed it down in his comment. I copied your servlet, tested it as follows:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2755338;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Those are indeed called sequentially.
        System.out.println("Starting to fire 3 requests in current thread...");
        new TestURL().run();
        new TestURL().run();
        new TestURL().run();
        System.out.println("Finished firing 3 requests in current thread!");

        // But those are called three at once.
        System.out.println("Starting to fire 3 requests in each its own thread...");
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        executor.submit(new TestURL());
        executor.submit(new TestURL());
        executor.submit(new TestURL());
        System.out.println("Finished firing 3 requests in each its own thread!");
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}

class TestURL implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Firing request...");
            new URL("http://localhost:8181/JavaEE6/test").openStream();
            System.out.println("Request finished!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And the results on the server side were:

```
INFO: start: http-thread-pool-8181-(2)
(10 seconds)
INFO: end: http-thread-pool-8181-(2)
INFO: start: http-thread-pool-8181-(1)
(10 seconds)
INFO: end: http-thread-pool-8181-(1)
INFO: start: http-thread-pool-8181-(2)
(10 seconds)
INFO: end: http-thread-pool-8181-(2)

INFO: start: http-thread-pool-8181-(1)
INFO: start: http-thread-pool-8181-(2)
INFO: start: http-thread-pool-8181-(3)
(10 seconds)
INFO: end: http-thread-pool-8181-(1)
INFO: end: http-thread-pool-8181-(2)
INFO: end: http-thread-pool-8181-(3)
```

Comment: I was manually sending requests using a browser (chrome)... Guess it doesn't actually send multiple requests if one of them is blocking ? In any case your client script works for me. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't miss my JMeter suggestion in the other comment ;)

Comment: Yup, I will definitely look into that. It's the beginning of my project, but hey, benchmark early, benchmark often :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the servlet running in single-thread mode ?
This would be in your web.xml